# Return false while uploading a file php

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that I'm trying upload a file with php code, but `move_uploaded_file()` function return false. What do I wrong?

My php code:

```php
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
  header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
  $destFile = "/root/mysite/upload_files/";

 if( $_FILES['avatar']['name'] != "" )
 {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $destFile . $fileName);
 }     
?>
```

Comment: Try `$destFile = getcwd() . "/root/mysite/upload_files/";` or probably `$destFile = getcwd() . "/upload_files/";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move\_upload\_file, return false but still working and not moving correctlly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368664/move-upload-file-return-false-but-still-working-and-not-moving-correctlly)

Comment: Is there a warning? According to the manual there could be a warning. Check your error reporting as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below.

```
// Upload file
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], '/root/mysite/upload_files/' . $_FILES['avatar']['name'])){
    die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
}

die('File uploaded successfully.');
```